# How to install libavcodec53 and libavformat53 so that I can use JavaFx in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-installation, java, libav, javafx

I want to use JavaFX in Ubuntu. According to [this link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/certconfig-2095354.html), I have to install `libavcodec53` and `libavformat53`. I googled and came across sites like [this](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/precise/libavcodec53), which suggests to use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libavcodec53
```

for Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04. I am using 16.04 version and for me the above commands did not work.

I also used the below command

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

But when I gave `sudo apt-cache search libav | grep extra-`, it didn’t give me any result.

So how am I supposed to install `libavcodec53` and `libavformat53` so that I can use JavaFx in Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: You don't need either to install libavcodec53 or libavformat53 anymore because since 16.04 JavaFX is included in the default Ubuntu repositories.

Answer (score 4):

You can either download JavaFX from the official Oracle website or install JavaFX from the default Ubuntu repositories.

### Oracle JavaFX

As of JDK 7u6 JavaFX is included with the standard JDK and JRE bundles.  Please [**download the JDK** or JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) to use JavaFX. Oracle Java Installation instructions are at this question: [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre).

On the same Oracle Java download page there is another link to download a Java SE Development Kit (JDK) Cobundle which contains JDK 8 with NetBeans IDE.

---

### Ubuntu JavaFX

In the Ubuntu 16.04 and later default repositories JavaFX is packaged as a separate package named *openjfx*. To install it, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install default-jdk openjfx
```

This command is a complete alternative to installing Oracle Java and JavaFX. Optionally you can install openjdk-11-jdk instead of or alongside openjdk-8-jdk in Ubuntu 18.04, and openjfx works with both JDKs.

You can also install NetBeans with this command:

```
sudo apt install netbeans
```

JavaFX can run all the JavaFX examples from the "Getting Started with JavaFX" tutorials at the official Oracle website successfully. The only difference from the Oracle tutorials is that in NetBeans openjfx doesn't add a *JavaFX Application* entry in the *File* -> *New Project* -> *Java* category, so you need to select *Java Application* instead.

Comment: I have already installed OracleJDK in my system.It already has javafx right?Moreover , I am able to run the code but the video is not getting played.So I think , I need to install the above libs..

Comment: So ,if that is the case,could u suggest me some way to install the above libs?

Comment: You don't ever need to install libavcodec53 or libavformat53 libraries which are both **obsolete packages from Ubuntu 12.04** because JavaFX is included in Oracle Java versions 7 and later. I don't know why your video isn't getting played, it depends on the format of the video and the codecs that are required to play it.

Comment: I have asked a question on this issue  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47806560/javafx-webview-html-video-playback-not-working-in-ubuntu).Could you have a look at it?

Comment: Now we're getting somewhere with Java because I can try your code from Stack Overflow. If this answered your question, you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer to change its color to green.

Comment: Sure..Thanks for trying my code..expecting your inputs...

Comment: I know that my JavaFX is installed correctly because my JavaFX program runs successfully in NetBeans in Ubuntu 16.04, but your Java code that you linked to at Stack Overflow shows errors in NetBeans, so I need to debug it.

Comment: does your JavaFX program play some html video?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70266/discussion-between-karel-and-george).