# Recent upgrade of openjfx broke my installed application

Tags: package-management, java, javafx

Today I ran `apt upgrade` on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and after that, an installed JavaFX 8 application (internally developed tool) stopped working.

Running the application only brings the following error:

```
$ java -jar app.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class ui.Main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, Canonical decided to ship a new version of openjfx. (Incidentally, is there a place where one can see such version changes/decisions?)

The relevant information can be found in `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2019-04-29  07:10:19
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: tannerli
Install: [snip]
Upgrade: [...]
openjfx:amd64 (8u161-b12-1ubuntu2, 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2)
openjfx-source:amd64 (8u161-b12-1ubuntu2, 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2)
libopenjfx-java:amd64 (8u161-b12-1ubuntu2, 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2)
libopenjfx-jni:amd64 (8u161-b12-1ubuntu2, 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2)
[...]
```

There's an open bug at [LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx/+bug/1799946) and quite a few similar questions on various StackExchange sites concerning this, [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088281/openjfx-11-after-18-10-upgrade) for example. None of those fit my specific needs. Seems there is no real solution to this day, only a

**Workaround**

Explictly downgrade all openjfx packages to the previous version:

```
$ sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 openjfx-source=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
```

Hold back the affected packages, so that the next `apt upgrade` won't break things again:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni openjfx openjfx-source
```

This will show up as info when you're upgrading next time:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
[...]
The following packages have been kept back:
  libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni openjfx openjfx-source
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Hi, when I try to use yor command to downgrade opejfx, I'm getting the following error. ```E: Version '8u161-b12-1ubuntu2' for 'openjfx' was not found```. How can we fix this?