# Downgrade openjfx on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: openjdk

I'm trying to Install the package Burai (https://nisihara.wixsite.com/burai) for DFT calculations. This package depends on the `openjfx` library and becaus of  recent bug in the openjfx I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class burai.app.QEFXMain
```

After some research I learned that this is caused due to some bug in the latest version and I'm trying to downgrade OpenJFX as indicated in this thread ([Recent upgrade of openjfx broke my installed application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1139155/recent-upgrade-of-openjfx-broke-my-installed-application)). I have used rmadison to get all the available versions in the apt-repo, and it gives the following output.

```
openjfx | 8u60-b27-4         | xenial/universe           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, powerpc, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 | bionic/universe           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el
 openjfx | 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 | bionic-security/universe  | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 11.0.2+1-1~18.04.2 | bionic-updates/universe   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 11.0.7+0-2ubuntu1  | focal/universe            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 11.0.7+0-2ubuntu2  | focal-updates/universe    | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 11.0.11+0-1        | impish/universe           | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 11.0.11+0-1        | jammy/universe            | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 11.0.11+0-1        | kinetic/universe          | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, s390x
 openjfx | 11.0.11+1-1        | kinetic-proposed/universe | source, amd64, ppc64el, s390x
```

I tried to downgrade, by the following command,

```
sudo apt install openjfx=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-java=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 libopenjfx-jni=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2 openjfx-source=8u161-b12-1ubuntu2
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Version '8u161-b12-1ubuntu2' for 'openjfx' was not found
```

This is weird, because the package openjfx is indeed available and this version is also available. How can we fix this?

Comment: The version that you are trying to download is only available from Bionic (18.04) ppa not jammy (22.04) ppa. Jammy installs version 11.0.11+0-1.

Comment: Is there any way to install the Bionic version on Jammy?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the problem was fixed when I downloaded the Java RE from the official Java website and used that instead of OpenJFX.